# Flink - Count processed messages for particular Task Manager

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

- Am using flink 1.17.0
- Flink application is running with 1 Job Manager and 2 Task Managers
- **Want to Query Task manager with below**

  **Query total number of messages processed**

  **Query a particular parameter from the processed messages list**

Are there any REST APIs to query Task Manager processed data?

Comment: You can refer to official  doc. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/rest_api/. Im not sure if there is an API that can query the number of messages processed for entire taskmanager, but there is an API for a job vertex."/jobs/:jobid/vertices/:vertexid/taskmanagers". I dont understand the meaning of second question.